# Можно ли добавить в ListView ...?

Tags: c#, uwp

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно добавить в `ListView` список с контролами собственного производства. Проблема в том, что мне нужно разграничивать их в списке, к примеру `TextBox`-ами, и так, что бы я не мог выбрать эти разграничители. Можно у нужных item-ов поставить `IsEnabled = false`, однако тогда эти item-ы тускнеют, и это мне не нужно.

На данный момент я создаю несколько `ListView` и заполняю их отдельно, ставя между ними разграничители. Однако это приводит к тому, что мне приходится при выборе одного item-а просматривать элементы всех `ListView`

Может кто знает, как добавлять `not selectable`  элементы в `ListView`?

Comment: Если вы используете настолько ручное управление, зачем вам `ListView`? Возьмите просто `StackPanel` и набросайте туда нужные элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен `ListView` и `CollectionViewSource` в качестве источника. Там можно делать группировку, разделители и всё что душе угодно.